# How to extract data from Travelport Universal API SOAP Response in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, travelport-api

I have received soap response from travelport universal API like that'

"http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v25_0" xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v25_0">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

```
    <air:FlightDetailsList>
        <air:FlightDetails Key="58XJnJpeSiWQh5SiibpeNA==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T07:50:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T10:51:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="121" TravelTime="121" Equipment="E70" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="WhW1HfPEQwaSmju/l4E6Rg==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T09:10:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T12:07:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="117" TravelTime="117" Equipment="M90" OnTimePerformance="80" DestinationTerminal="1"/><air:FlightDetails Key="NAeJgKmARUepUCAcPcZG9A==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T10:01:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T12:59:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="118" TravelTime="118" Equipment="CR7" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="GCJBOHKSR6+HpS49Kq3FlQ==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T11:10:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T14:09:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="119" TravelTime="119" Equipment="320" OnTimePerformance="70" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="+QSdRjc6TOqOoXVllZswBQ==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T12:15:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T15:07:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="112" TravelTime="112" Equipment="320" OnTimePerformance="80" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="e+HK+Ww7ReaY16cN+3yvwg==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T13:09:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T16:10:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="121" TravelTime="121" Equipment="E70" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="WIY1Ne3STHGEDoSstw8lIA==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T13:25:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T16:20:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="115" TravelTime="115" Equipment="M90" OnTimePerformance="70" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="ci64sRQ/St2d5kZzXMwvuA==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T15:40:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T18:36:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="116" TravelTime="116" Equipment="M90" OnTimePerformance="40" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="VGXriV3/TUqrgdGX72j1vw==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T15:40:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T18:36:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="116" TravelTime="116" Equipment="M90" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="D3bfr6rITo+fZcE0uT/69g==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T16:25:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T19:14:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="109" TravelTime="109" Equipment="319" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="LDoBajFVRI+OdsJ+w+l+ng==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T18:00:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T20:55:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="115" TravelTime="115" Equipment="738" OnTimePerformance="70" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="et9yaxFoQC2Uau/qyX/qwQ==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T18:00:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T20:55:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="115" TravelTime="115" Equipment="738" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="C6gsolXKRXezd/WVM9C9PQ==" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T20:15:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T23:09:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="114" TravelTime="114" Equipment="319" DestinationTerminal="1"/>

        <air:FlightDetails Key="9epWOdctS6aGqD/Sjo9xiQ==" Origin="DEN" Destination="FSD" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T14:27:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T16:59:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="92" TravelTime="175" Equipment="CRJ"/><air:FlightDetails Key="fXbBZ4k9T9GoLXILAI5UHw==" Origin="FSD" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T17:20:00.000-05:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T18:22:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="62" TravelTime="175" Equipment="CRJ" OnTimePerformance="50" DestinationTerminal="1"/>
```

```
<air:AirSegmentList>
    <air:AirSegment Key="lJ5ELp80S56zdl77CLHxcA==" Group="0" Carrier="UA" FlightNumber="3534" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T07:50:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T10:51:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="121" TravelTime="121" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="E70" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="AvailStatusTTY">

<air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
    <air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="F6|J6|C5|A5|D5|Z4|P4"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|E9|U9|H9|Q9|V9|W9|S9|T9|L9|K9|G9|N9"/>
    </air:AirAvailInfo>
<air:FlightDetailsRef Key="58XJnJpeSiWQh5SiibpeNA=="/>
</air:AirSegment>

<air:AirSegment Key="SdmoVvIpStGg6lyrkIYorA==" Group="0" Carrier="DL" FlightNumber="1608" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T09:10:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T12:07:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="117" TravelTime="117" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="M90" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="StatusOverlaid">

<air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G">
<air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="FA|PA|AA|GA"/>

<air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="SA|YA|BA|MA|HA|QA|KA|LA|UA|TA|VA|XA|EA"/>
</air:AirAvailInfo>

<air:FlightDetailsRef Key="WhW1HfPEQwaSmju/l4E6Rg=="/>
</air:AirSegment>
<air:AirSegment Key="UatLZ1InQoGRb5kJpb6s2g==" Group="0" Carrier="UA" FlightNumber="3641" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T10:01:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T12:59:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="118" TravelTime="118" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="CR7" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="AvailStatusTTY">

<air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="F6|J6|C5|A5|D5|Z4|P4"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|E9|U9|H9|Q9|V9|W9|S9|T9|L9|K9|G9|NR"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="NAeJgKmARUepUCAcPcZG9A=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="v3l96M+1SW6k4MvCfRPEaw==" Group="0" Carrier="DL" FlightNumber="220" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T11:10:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T14:09:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="119" TravelTime="119" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="StatusOverlaid"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="FA|PA|AA|GL"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="SA|YA|BA|MA|HA|QA|KA|LA|UA|TA|VA|XA|EA"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="GCJBOHKSR6+HpS49Kq3FlQ=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="2OUTPZDIThyw+k4lcjZTaw==" Group="0" Carrier="F9" FlightNumber="112" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T12:15:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T15:07:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="112" TravelTime="112" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="320" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="Seamless"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y7|B7|H7|V7|L7|U7|E7|D7|M7|Q7|T7|G7|W7|R0|Z0|S7|K0"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="+QSdRjc6TOqOoXVllZswBQ=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="JWy1PYRnQFOqPGy+ERW1BQ==" Group="0" Carrier="UA" FlightNumber="3545" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T13:09:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T16:10:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="121" TravelTime="121" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="E70" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="AvailStatusTTY"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="F6|J6|C6|A6|D6|Z5|P5"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|E9|U9|H9|Q9|V9|W9|S9|T9|L9|K9|G9|NR"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="e+HK+Ww7ReaY16cN+3yvwg=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="zib1KU1VQxaytipyLUxrHw==" Group="0" Carrier="DL" FlightNumber="2108" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T13:25:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T16:20:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="115" TravelTime="115" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="M90" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="StatusOverlaid"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="FA|PA|AA|GA"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="SA|YA|BA|MA|HA|QA|KA|LA|UA|TA|VA|XA|EA"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="WIY1Ne3STHGEDoSstw8lIA=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="FC8d7jIcQEOr/oFpVgqndg==" Group="0" Carrier="DL" FlightNumber="2149" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T15:40:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T18:36:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="116" TravelTime="116" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="M90" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="StatusOverlaid"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="FA|PA|AA|GA"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="SA|YA|BA|MA|HA|QA|KA|LA|UA|TA|VA|XA|EA"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="ci64sRQ/St2d5kZzXMwvuA=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="OovkfVJrR1GxhwKo8MTRkg==" Group="0" Carrier="VS" FlightNumber="5556" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T15:40:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T18:36:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="116" TravelTime="116" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="M90" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="Seamless"><air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="DL" OperatingFlightNumber="2149"/><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="J9|C9|D9|I9|Z9"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumEconomy" BookingCounts="W9|S9|H9|K9"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|R9|L9|U9|M9|E9|Q9|X9|N9|O9"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="VGXriV3/TUqrgdGX72j1vw=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="9xxF72fOQMGzdJgT/LO1rQ==" Group="0" Carrier="F9" FlightNumber="114" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T16:25:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T19:14:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="109" TravelTime="109" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="319" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="Seamless"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y7|B7|H7|V7|L7|U7|E7|D7|M7|Q7|T7|G7|W0|R0|Z0|S7|K0"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="D3bfr6rITo+fZcE0uT/69g=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="nfJa834FSmGXCntJM11vjQ==" Group="0" Carrier="DL" FlightNumber="2008" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T18:00:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T20:55:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="115" TravelTime="115" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="738" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="StatusOverlaid"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="FA|PA|AA|GA"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="SA|YA|BA|MA|HA|QA|KA|LA|UA|TA|VA|XA|EA"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="LDoBajFVRI+OdsJ+w+l+ng=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="GfdoqbgiSqeuOoNQ2sR/UA==" Group="0" Carrier="VS" FlightNumber="5554" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T18:00:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T20:55:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="115" TravelTime="115" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="738" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail used" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="Seamless"><air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="DL" OperatingFlightNumber="2008"/><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Business" BookingCounts="J9|C9|D9|I9|Z9"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="PremiumEconomy" BookingCounts="W9|S9|H9|K9"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|R9|L9|U9|M9|E9|Q9|X9|N9|O9"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="et9yaxFoQC2Uau/qyX/qwQ=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="kGljXijJSTuEmRueo3ojSw==" Group="0" Carrier="UA" FlightNumber="598" Origin="DEN" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T20:15:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T23:09:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="114" TravelTime="114" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="319" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="AvailStatusTTY"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="First" BookingCounts="F9|J9|C9|A9|D9|Z5|P5"/><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|E9|U9|H9|Q9|V9|W9|S9|T9|L9|K9|G9|N9"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="C6gsolXKRXezd/WVM9C9PQ=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="Q4wsolcnRzSL9czPKQN0RQ==" Group="0" Carrier="UA" FlightNumber="5234" Origin="DEN" Destination="FSD" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T14:27:00.000-06:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T16:59:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="92" TravelTime="175" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="CRJ" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="AvailStatusTTY"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="Y9|B9|M9|E9|U9|H9|Q9|V9|W9|S9|T9|L9|K5|GR|NR"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="9epWOdctS6aGqD/Sjo9xiQ=="/></air:AirSegment><air:AirSegment Key="YdFjk62OSF2DVpLek/VHFg==" Group="0" Carrier="DL" FlightNumber="3516" Origin="FSD" Destination="MSP" DepartureTime="2014-04-15T17:20:00.000-05:00" ArrivalTime="2014-04-15T18:22:00.000-05:00" FlightTime="62" TravelTime="175" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="CRJ" ChangeOfPlane="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="Polled avail exists" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" AvailabilitySource="StatusOverlaid"><air:AirAvailInfo ProviderCode="1G"><air:BookingCodeInfo CabinClass="Economy" BookingCounts="SA|YA|BA|MA|HA|QA|KA|LA|UA|TL|VL|XL|EL"/></air:AirAvailInfo><air:FlightDetailsRef Key="fXbBZ4k9T9GoLXILAI5UHw=="/></air:AirSegment></air:AirSegmentList><air:AirItinerarySolution Key="ZG8LeABlQIefBy3+nFhFSQ=="><air:AirSegmentRef Key="lJ5ELp80S56zdl77CLHxcA=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="SdmoVvIpStGg6lyrkIYorA=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="UatLZ1InQoGRb5kJpb6s2g=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="v3l96M+1SW6k4MvCfRPEaw=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="2OUTPZDIThyw+k4lcjZTaw=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="JWy1PYRnQFOqPGy+ERW1BQ=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="zib1KU1VQxaytipyLUxrHw=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="FC8d7jIcQEOr/oFpVgqndg=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="OovkfVJrR1GxhwKo8MTRkg=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="9xxF72fOQMGzdJgT/LO1rQ=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="nfJa834FSmGXCntJM11vjQ=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="GfdoqbgiSqeuOoNQ2sR/UA=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="kGljXijJSTuEmRueo3ojSw=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="Q4wsolcnRzSL9czPKQN0RQ=="/><air:AirSegmentRef Key="YdFjk62OSF2DVpLek/VHFg=="/><air:Connection SegmentIndex="13"/></air:AirItinerarySolution></air:AvailabilitySearchRsp></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle SOAP responses is to use SoapClient classmap option so you'll only deal with PHP objects. In you case you would then have for example an array of ojects.

The SoapClient classmap option allows to map PHP classes to response elements. To easily create/generate the PHP classes that represent the response elements, you should look to [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/mikaelcom/WsdlToPhp) that you can use online at [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com/).